# File 'utf8x.def' not found error in TeXstudio on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: errors, texstudio, unicode, ubuntu

I'm trying to compile a .tex file (which I know to be working in Windows' TeXstudio), however in Ubuntu installation (with `sudo apt-get install texstudio`), I get the following error:

```
File `utf8x.def' not found. \endinput
```

I think this is because I have `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` in my preamble, but don't know how to fix the issue.

Thanks for any help,

### Edit:

Thanks to the suggestions, I changed `utf8x` to `utf8`, but now the line `\usepackage{cite}` gives this error:

```
File `footmisc.sty' not found. \usepackage
```

Comment: exactly why are you using `utf8x` and not `utf8` (just asking)?

Comment: Also remember that if you installed TeX Live through Ubuntu, then TeX Live is split up into many many components and as swoop... mentions you may need to search in other to know which Ubuntu TeX Live parts needs to be installed. I personally tend to use upstream TeX Live (or recommend installaing `texlive-full` which installs everything (HD space is cheap)

Comment: After removing the `x`, I got another package error. I will install `texlive-full` and see if it' fixed. Thanks for all the help,

Comment: Exactly which error? Others my run into the same problem, so for the archives it might be better to update your question with this information.

Comment: I updated the question with the new error, but I think the errors will keep coming and coming as I solve each one manually. So I'm currently hoping texlive will solve all the issues at once :)

Comment: Now you know why I just recommend upstream or at least just install everything. But `apt-file ` is a nice tool to resolve the issues if you don't want to install it all (with a the full installation you will end up with a lot you'll never use)

Comment: Yes, texlive solved all the issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to see if utf8x is installed?

You could try `apt-file -x search '/ucs.sty$'`

According to CTAN this is [included in texlive](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ucs), so install this if not already installed.

Answer (score 12):

If you installed with `apt-get`, use `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`

If you happened to install otherwise such as BasicTeX, Windows, or a manual install on Linux, you can use `tlmgr` and run `sudo tlmgr install ucs`.